# Setting up infopath

Tags: infopath

How do I get InfoPath? I click on `Customize Form` on my site and it says `Microsoft 2010 is required to use this feature`. Where can I get a download to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean it is NOT on your computer or on the original set up file/installation CD.

It's in MSOffice Professional Plus

coastalsoftware.co.uk/microsoft-office/2010-suites/professional-plus-1-install

Comment: Office 2010 Professional includes:
Word 2010
Excel 2010
Outlook 2010
OneNote 2010
PowerPoint 2010
Publisher 2010
Access 2010
Which ones info path then?

Comment: Office 2010 Professional and Office 2010 Professional Plus both are different editions.  

InfoPath 2010 will be available in Office 2010 Professional Plus.

Answer (score 0):

InfopPath 2010 may still be found in a box online somewhere, though no longer at Microsoft. The easiest way to get InfoPath 2013 these days is probably to subscribe to Office 365, Midsize Business or higher. There's no real difference between 2010 and 2013.

Details here:

http://www.formotus.com/15444/blog-infopath/need-infopath-heres-how-to-get-it-today